# newbie F# trie implementation gone wrong

Tags: f#, trie

I am trying to implement a trie data structure in F#.
I am having some problems.
I cannot debug the word insertion function. None of my breakpoint inside this function is reached something crashes but I don't see any error.
Also I am having serious doubts if I implemented the thing right.
Anyway here is the code:

```
type TrieNode =
    | SubNodes of char * bool * TrieNode list
    | Nil
    member this.Char = match this with | Nil -> ' '
                                       | SubNodes(c,weh,subnodes) -> c
    member this.GetChild(c:char) = match this with  | Nil -> []
                                                    | SubNodes(c,weh,subnodes) ->[ (List.filter(fun (this:TrieNode) -> this.Char = c) subnodes).Head ]

    member this.AWordEndsHere = match this with | Nil -> false
                                                | SubNodes(c,weh,subnodes) -> weh
module TrieFunctions = 
    let rec insertWord (wordChars:char list) = function
        | Nil -> SubNodes(wordChars.Head, false, [])
        | SubNodes(c, weh, subnodes) as node ->
            let child = node.GetChild(wordChars.Head)
            if child = [] then 
                SubNodes(wordChars.Head,false,[insertWord wordChars.Tail node])
            else
                SubNodes(wordChars.Head,false,[insertWord wordChars.Tail child.Head])


type Trie(inner : TrieNode) =

    member this.InsertWord(wordChars:char list) = TrieFunctions.insertWord(wordChars)


  let trie = Trie(SubNodes(' ',false,List.empty)).InsertWord(['g';'i';'g';'i'])
```

So my questions are:
1. how can I get debug access to the insertWord function? Why am I not getting it now? Why am I not seeing an error?
2. How can I make the function insert word return a list of TrieNode objects so that I won't have to wrap the call around square brackets ("[","]"). I think this is an error.
3. Any other advice you can give me on implementing this data structure in F# is welcomed I know I must be doing a lot of things wrong as I am very new to this language. I know for example that the word insertion function is flawed because it doesn't check if the list is empty or not so it ends prematurely. I wanted to cross that bridge when I got to it.

Thank you in advance

Thank you in advance

Comment: Didn't want to edit without making sure - you mean a Tree, right?
An extension of a list and a binary tree?

Comment: the trie value at the end ends up being of type (Trie -> Trie) - which suggests to me that it is partially evaluating insertWord

Comment: trie as in prefix tree not tree as in a plain tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are probably failing to trigger your breakpoint because you aren't fully applying `insertWords`: it takes two curried parameters, but you're only passing the single argument `wordChars` in.  Perhaps you meant to define your `Trie` type like this instead?

   ```
   type Trie(inner : TrieNode) =
     member this.InsertWord(wordChars:char list) = TrieFunctions.insertWord wordChars inner
   ```
2. Well, you could wrap all of your return values in `[]` to make them singleton lists and then not wrap the recursive calls to `insertWords`.  However, it seems likely that there's something wrong with your algorithm (either way), since you only ever get singleton lists...

   Note that at the moment you're completely discarding the existing `subnodes` list - if you want to append to the front of it, use `(insertWord wordChards.Tail node)::subnodes` instead.  However, sometimes you'll want to replace an existing entry rather than append a new one, which will require more effort.
3. There are several issues.  Here are a few to get you started:

   - Try to avoid using `Head`, particularly since you don't always know that your lists are non-empty when you're calling it.
   - When you're inserting a word into an empty `Trie`, you're dropping all but the first character!  Similarly, you need to reconsider your recursive calls too.
   - More importantly, your `TrieNode` type has a bit of a problem.  Can you write out the resulting trie you would expect to see which just contains the two words `"in"` and `"to"`?

Comment: thank you for you answer but regarding point no 2 singleton lists are exactly what I want to avoid what I don't know is how to avoid them I want actual lists instead

Comment: @Para - if you resolve the issues in point 3, point 2 should take care of itself, but I've added a few more thoughts anyway.  Try walking through a few very simple examples on paper.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, as @kvb said, you're partially applying `insertWord`. While defining it you are specifying an explicit argument `wordChars` and by using the `function` construct for pattern matching you're basically adding a second parameter of type `TrieNode` so your function ends up with the following signature:

```
insertWord : char list -> TrieNode -> TrieNode
```

Since in your call to `InsertWord` (which is just a wrapper to `insertWord`) you only provide one argument (a char list) the function won't get called, but you'll get a function expecting a `TrieNode` back. `InsertWord`'s signature makes that clear:

```
InsertWord : wordChars:char list -> (TrieNode -> TrieNode)
```

Note the parenthesis.

You'll probably want to provide a `Nil` in your case since conceptually you're extending an empty trie:

```
let trie = Trie(SubNodes(' ',false,List.empty)).InsertWord(['g';'i';'g';'i']) Nil
```

You'll find an example implementation of a trie structure here: http://lepensemoi.free.fr/index.php/2009/10/15/trie-and-anagrams-with-f